# Does RAID 1 improve random read latency?

Tags: raid, software-raid, raid-1

Specifically, in the cases of `mdraid` and Intel Rapid Storage.

If so, is it done by "racing" the disks, or is only the "less busy" disk that's queried?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:  It can if you have multiple simultaneous random read operations targeted at the RAID-1 set.  If you have a single stream requesting reads serially then there won't be any improvement over the physical speed of the drive.

The maximum speed up for read latency is the single disk latency time divided by the number of disks, e.g. a 2 disk RAID-1 will go twice as fast at absolute best, and the same speed at worst.

If you care about writes, remember that RAID-1 actually slows them down slightly as the write isn't completed until both disks are updated and as one disk is rotationally farther away from the target than the other the synchronization takes longer.  This does not average out to the single disk time, it actually increases the write latency with the number of disks in the RAID-1 set (usually 2).  The increase is a function of the rotation time.